# Cumulative integral of time series

Tags: r, time-series

how can single and double cumulative integral be calculated in R for a time series

```
dput(ps)
structure(c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 6L), class = c("xts", 
"zoo"), .indexCLASS = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), .indexTZ = "", tzone = "", index = structure(c(1409522400, 
1409523300, 1409524200, 1409525100, 1409526000, 1409526900, 1409527800, 
1409528700, 1409529600, 1409530500, 1409531400, 1409532300, 1409533200, 
1409534100, 1409535000, 1409535900, 1409536800, 1409537700, 1409538600, 
1409539500, 1409540400, 1409541300, 1409542200, 1409543100), tzone = "", tclass = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt")), .Dim = c(24L, 1L))
```

Comment: `cumsum` is the inverse of `diff` (see my previous answer).

Comment: @BenBolker ..well, almost. The result of `cumsum(diff(x))` is not equal to that of `diff(cumsum(x))`. Usually the former drops the last element of the sequence `x`, the latter the first element. In a decreasing series like `x<-c(10:1)` the differences are even larger.